# Text Wrapping Is Changing When I Press Play Unity(Closed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

So I'm making a game with text as the diolauge and I turn off overflow in the tmp settings. And when I press play it just turns back on again I have some images as example. And I tried restarting unity but that didn't work.

[image: Before Play]

[image: After Play]

Comment: Compare the inspectors before/after play to try pinpoint the issue in layout.

Comment: The only change is that the wrapping changed on when I pressed play and goes back to off when I stop playing

Comment: What you can do is right-click each of these component you suspect and open them as individual windows so you can see them all at once on your screen. Then, watch carefully what changes in each of them. There's a strong possibility that some TMP property is responsible for this change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it on my own! I just had to use  GetComponent().enableWordWrapping = true; in the start method!